# I have used this code for group button but it display button in vertical view but i have display in horizontal

Tags: ios, iphone

```
 NSMutableArray* buttons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
    CGRect btnRect = CGRectMake(25, 320, 100, 30);

    for (NSString* optionTitle in @[@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", @"Pink" ,@"Black"]){

        RadioButton* btn = [[RadioButton alloc] initWithFrame:btnRect];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(onRadioButtonValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        btnRect.origin.y += 40;
        [btn setTitle:optionTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 6, 0, 0);
        [self.view addSubview:btn];
        [buttons addObject:btn];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the btnRect value accordingly :

```
btnRect.origin.y += 40;
```

Should be changed as :

```
btnRect.origin.x = (btnRect.size.width + btnRect.origin.x) + 5.0;
// 5.0 value can be changed to what ever you want according to the distance required between two buttons
```